# Issue with xml xs:unique

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, unique

My xs:unique is not working. I tried various solutions provided in this site. None of them seem to be worked for me. I am using C# to validate my xml against the schema. For example key passwordomni is repeated.

Below is my schema.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/SqlManifest.xsd">
  <xs:element name="sqlmanifest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="sqlparameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="sqlparameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="required"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="required"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="unique-key">
                  <xs:selector xpath ="mstns:sqlparameter"/>
                  <xs:field xpath="@key"/>
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="sqlcommands" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="sqlcommand" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="path" use="required"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="unique-path">
                  <xs:selector xpath ="mstns:sqlcommand"/>
                  <xs:field xpath="@path"/>
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="transactional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Below is my xml

```
<sqlmanifest transactional="false">
    <sqlparameters>
        <sqlparameter key="dbpath" description="Please enter dbpath"/>
        <sqlparameter key="passworduserOmni" description="Please enter password for OmniUser"/>
        <sqlparameter key="passwordadminOmni" description="Please enter password for OmniAdminUser"/>
                <sqlparameter key="passwordadminOmni" description="Please enter password for OmniAdminUser"/>
    </sqlparameters>
    <sqlcommands>
        <sqlcommand path="scripts/script1.sql"/> 
        <sqlcommand path="scripts/script2.sql" />
        <sqlcommand path="scripts/scripts3.sql" />
        <sqlcommand path="scripts/scripts4.sql" />  
                <sqlcommand path="scripts/script1.sql"/> 
    </sqlcommands>
</sqlmanifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML doesn't uses namespaces, therefore your XSD should have no target namespace, so you must not use any prefixes in your XPaths (fields/selectors).

Constraints must be placed at the appropriate level. So your `unique-key` must be moved under `sqlparameters` and `unique-path` under `sqlcommands`.

Your corrected XSD follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/SqlManifest.xsd">
    <xs:element name="sqlmanifest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sqlparameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="sqlparameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="unique-key">
                        <xs:selector xpath ="sqlparameter"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@key"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="sqlcommands" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="sqlcommand" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="path" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="unique-path">
                        <xs:selector xpath ="sqlcommand"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@path"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="transactional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you visualize the constraints before and after, it would help you understand why the scope should be the way it is; also, considering that the selector xpath is rooted at the element, it wouldn't match as per your expectations.

[image]